# layout_weight vs multiple sw<dp> screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am still confused between the two. Do I have to create multiple layouts for my app like `sw600dp` and `sw720dp` if I used a `LinearLayout` and specified a `layout_weight` attribute for each view?
In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#) it describes the `layout_weight` as how much a child will occupy from the screen. So will that be an alternative of creating multiple layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less an opinion based answer.
However, I prefer creating multiple layouts for different sizes.

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

So the usage would be creating a new layout file using the screen size parameter. And to finally answer your question: No, it's better to have multiple layouts, but you should always work with a combination of both.

You sometimes don't want to have the same content on different screen sizes. For example an app cannot upscale from small to a big tablet. On tablets the app should look different and have more content, other locations. You cannot control that in a single file. For simple upscaling you can use a single file and weights. But if you need to make changes to the way the content is displayed, it's better to use different files.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, one might include layout_weight attribute and a LinearLayout in those multiple layouts and in most cases the values will be the same.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is better to have multiple layouts and in which manner it is better?

Comment: There you go. ;-)